# DataTable not showing pagination buttons and records info - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

Using Datatable plugin for pagination, I can't get it to display pagination buttons and records information ("Showing X out of Y Records"). It is fetching the records correctly when I am selecting the page size from the drop down just above the table, but for some reason, it is not showing pagination buttons.

My guess is that it has to know the Total Record count of the table, and I am giving it that in the ""iTotalRecords": 10000" part, I have 1000 records in my table, but still it is of no use. What exactly am I missing here?

It is passing the `start` (page number) and `length` (page size) params correctly.
Below is my code,

```
$('#leadDetailTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "info": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, 500], [10, 50, 100, 500]],
        "iTotalRecords": 10000,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "searching": false,
        "scrollY": false,
        "scrollX": false,
        "ajax":{
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchLeads", "ResourceManagement")',
            data: args,
            success: function (result) {
                /* Do things with result */
            },

        }
    });
```

Comment: Are they in the DOM but hidden?

Comment: `<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="leadDetailTable_paginate"></div>`

Only this div is shown in the DOM.

Comment: And are there any warnings in the console?

Comment: Hi @Anss, did you get any solution for the thing which you mentioned? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hello @Jivan, I don't quite remember how I got past this but I will strongly recommend you to check the answer given below, the response of the ajax request must contain all the required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding following parameters:

```
 "bPaginate":true,
 "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
 "bLengthChange": true,
 "bInfo" : true
```

Comment: Didn't work. All the examples I have seen does not require special params for pagination, I guess it's turned on by default, are you sure the part wher e I am giving total count of records is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because I returned the wrong `recordsFiltered` value from the server-side. Make sure that the `recordsTotal` value represents the number of records(rows) in the table and the `recordsFiltered` value represents the number of rows that should stay hidden of the total rows. DataTables uses this information to create the pagination buttons.

Comment: can you give more explanation OR can you give resources related to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the below property

`"pagingType": "full_numbers"`

Comment: I am trying these options found in the documentation of DataTables, but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

What is the response being returned by the ajax request? It should include the following:

```
{
    data: <the array of row data>,
    draw: <the same value the request had for its draw value>,
    recordsTotal: <the total number of records>,
    recordsFiltered: <the total number of records after filtering>
}
```

If you don't want it to say "filtered from x records", then count the records after filtering and set both recordsTotal and recordsFiltered to that value.